# What are the best options for a generating a secure SSL certificate/csr?

Tags: openssl

To preface, I have searched a lot but can't seem to find the right search terms.

I generated a CSR using the following command:

```
openssl req -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/ssl/ssl.key -out /etc/ssl/ssl.csr
```

With the generated CSR I got a class 2 signed cert via StartSSL.

The issue is when I view the cert info in Chrome on my site, it says the site security is outdated.

Is maybe there is an Apache2 mod_ssl setting I need to change?

Or if it's a cert issue, what OpenSSL options do I need to use to generate an up-to-date CSR request?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That presumably has to do with the SHA1 hash algorithm used to sign the certificate. See Google announcement [here](http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.nl/2014/09/gradually-sunsetting-sha-1.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, add "-sha256" to your CSR command, to ensure that you're using SHA256 instead of the less secure SHA1 or MD5 hash digests for your certificate.

Second, check to ensure that the server itself is configured to use only TLS or above.  Change your SSL configuration lines (in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf`, your site files, or wherever else your distro is storing them) to be at a bare minimum this restrictive:

```
SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:-MEDIUM:-LOW
```

For more information, there is a document specifying the lowest acceptable algorithms and key strengths on the [CA/Browser Forum](https://cabforum.org/wp-content/uploads/BRv1.2.3.pdf), in Appendix A. That link is likely to become outdated as new standards are adopted, so keep an eye on their [Baseline Requirements Documents](https://cabforum.org/baseline-requirements-documents/) page for updates.

Comment: Would this be correct for CSR? `openssl req -x509 -nodes -sha256 -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout techglimpse.com.key -out techglimpse.com.crt` and this is my current ssl config: `SSLCipherSuite AES256-SHA:RC4-SHA:AES128-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5 SSLHonorCipherOrder on`

Comment: Also, should -days match the cert signing length? Class 2 StartSSL are good for 2 years

Comment: You can compare the ciphers used for SSL/TLS transmission security with `openssl ciphers -v '<string>'`. Just copy and paste the SSLCipherSuite values in there and see what differences there are.

Comment: @GeoStyx: The `-days` is only relevant in combination with the `-x509` flag where you're generating a self-signed certificate. The validity period of the signed certificate is not set in the CSR, but by the CA when they create the signed certificate and probably based on how much money you gave them.

Comment: @HBruijn Ok, so do I not need the -x509? Would this command be what I want? `openssl req -nodes -sha256 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout ssl.key -out ssl.crt`

Comment: Yep, but since you're creating a certificate signing just to keep things straight `-out ssl.csr`

Comment: @HBruijn Thank you so much! I rally appreciate the help :)